# Meteor mizzaou user-status package

Tags: meteor

I am not able to find more detailed docs than [these](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status). I am having issues in using status.idle. It is always false for online users even if the user is doing nothing( has been idle for more than 10mins). 
I am not sure how is it diff from status.online then. 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here, idle is always false when user is online. I need it to be based upon the user activity.

Heres the server side code :

```
Meteor.publish('usersIdle', function(id){
if(this.userId){
    let users = DTU.find({dTId : id}).fetch();
    let dUId = _.pluck(users, 'userId');
    console.log(UserStatus.connections.find({userId : {$in : doubtUsersId}, idle : false}).fetch())
    return UserStatus.connections.find({userId : {$in : doubtUsersId}});
}
});
```

But here the 'idle' field is defined in the object.

Comment: Show us some supporting code to figure out what is going on.

Comment: actually i havent wriiten any code yet. I have just added mizzau user-status package to my app and I am exploring its usability for my app. It always shows idle as false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add the package, you have `UserStatus` object that is made available on the client side (and the server, but as an example, lets look at the client side object).

A typical scenario would be:

1. Once the user logs in successfully, call [`UserStatus.startMonitor()`](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status#client-api) which will listen to key presses, mouse clicks.
2. Once the user logs out, call [`UserStatus.stopMonitor()`](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status#client-api) to stop monitoring.

You then have an `UserStatus.isIdle()` reactive var that tells you whether that particular user is idle or not. You may use this status - for example, to log out the user. The same is also available on the server side. I'm not sure if you should explicitly write the status to `Meteor.users.status.idle` though.

You can check out the demo application [here](http://user-status.meteorapp.com/). It's source code is [here](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status/blob/master/demo/demo.coffee)

Comment: I want information about all users and hence I am writing server side code. Code added for more details

Comment: Yes, well, you have to manually enable the idleMonitoring first, as per the documentation. Then you can check  the  ```UserStatus.connections``` collection on the server side. [ PS: as a rule of thumb, sanitize sensitive information before sharing. You seem to have a valid telephone number showing up in the screenshot. :) ]

Comment: Oh I didnt realise about the phone number. Thanks!. Though, how to enable idleMonitoring ?

Comment: As I've mentioned, it won't get enabled until you call ```UserStatus.startMontior(options)``` on the client.